# Reverse Geocoding using latitude and longitude for iPhone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, core-location, reverse-geocoding

I need to reverse geocode based on latitude and longitude. Actually this is for my iPhone application where I get the latitude and longitude from core location api and pass that to the back end. Using those values server do the reverse geocoding and grab the address. So my concern is that the google reverse geocoding API is not permitted to use without the map as they say.

"Note:  the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited. For complete details on allowed usage, consult the Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions."

So how do I capture user locations (country, state) for my iPhone? If there is a way to get that from iPhone SDK its also better.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [MKReverseGeocoder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) provided in the MapKit.

**Edit:**
Sorry, I misunderstood your question.  You'll have to use a 3rd party reverse geocoder then.  For example, try www.geonames.org.

Comment: Still it has the issue. It says "The Google terms of service require that the reverse geocoding service be used in conjunction with a Google map; take this into account when designing your application's user interface.". Can I use it without using the google map? This is what I need to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your reply aBitObvious. But I need a 3rd party service which can be invoked by objective C and it should be accepted by the apple. Do you know any?

Comment: It's a web service so you can use NSURLConnection or similar to call it.  AFAIK, it should not be a problem using whatever service you want.  I think Apple is only saying you must the MK reverse geocoder with the MK map and not by itself.  If you're really worried, email Apple support directly.